# Implicit function theorem / Implicit selections when Jacobian not invertible

Tags: real-analysis, differential-calculus, matrix-inverse, inverse-problems, implicit-function-theorem

I saw the attached result in the book by Dontchev and Rockafellar.

[image]

It requires the Jacobian to be of full rank m. I suspect this condition can be further relaxed. Assume that we know that the columns of $\nabla_p f(\bar p, \bar x)$ are in the  column space of A. Couldn't we conclude that

$$
\nabla s(\bar p) = A^\dagger \nabla_p f(\bar p, \bar x),
$$
where $\dagger$ represents the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse.

If true, is there a good reference I can read to learn about such a result and its extensions?